# error when accessing latitude and longitude value in geolib

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

In my react native app I have used geolib to find the nearest place to a certain point from a list of places, like this

```
const nearestPlace = geolib.findNearest({ latitude:6.4423456, longitude:75.9095818 }, (places));
```

once I console log nearestPlace I get one latitude, longitude pair but when I try to get the value of the latitude like this,

```
const latitudeValue = nearestPlace.latitude
```

It's giving me an error saying property latitude does not exist on type 'GeolibInputCoordinates' so I can't get the latitude value.

Any Idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use the [getLatitude](https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib#geolibgetlatitudepoint-raw--false), [getLongitude](https://github.com/manuelbieh/Geolib#geolibgetlongitudepoint-raw--false) functions. This will give you values for the latitude and longitude.

Perhaps your places array is in a different format such as { lat, lon } and this is what is causing the issue. They may not necessarily have a latitude or longitude property.

```js
const places = [{ lat: 6.45, lon: 75.90 }, { lat: 6.44, lon: 75.91 }];
let nearestPlace = geolib.findNearest({ latitude: 6.4423456, longitude: 75.9095818 }, (places));
console.log('Nearest place:', nearestPlace);

const latitudeValue = geolib.getLatitude(nearestPlace);
const longitudeValue = geolib.getLongitude(nearestPlace);

console.log('Latitude:', latitudeValue);
console.log('Longitude:', longitudeValue);

// You can also 'normalize' this like so: 

const point = { latitude: latitudeValue, longitude: longitudeValue};
console.log('Nearest point (normalized):', point);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/geolib@3.3.1/lib/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks, @Terry. Yes, I first changed the format of my places array to {latitude, longitude} it was in {Latitude, Longitude} format. Then I added '?' like this                                       
        const latitudeValue = nearestPlace?.latitude                                                           Then the problem was solved I hope that it doesn't give any errors in the future.

Comment: Ah, yes, optional chaining, very useful feature! Glad you got it working!